# Finding the min in a column where two other columns are zero

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a MySQL search that will find the lowest `imageID` where the other two columns = 0. In this case the `imageID` returned would be 8.

```
ImageId   Processing   Finished
  5           0           1
  6           1           0
  7           0           1
  8           0           0
  9           1           0
  10          0           1
  11          1           0
  12          0           0
  13          0           0 
  14          0           0
  15          0           0
```

Comment: Didn't any of the following answers help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(ImageId) from tablename where processing=0 and finished=0;
```

This is fairly basic SQL, and can easily be found if you do some research of your own.

Answer (score 2):

> find the lowest imageID where the other two columns = 0

Just convert your sentence in the query:

```
(find)    (the lowest imageID) (where the other two columns = 0)  
[SELECT]   [MIN(imageID)]      [WHERE Processing = 0 AND Finished = 0]
```

So your full query should be (using [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) aggregate function):

```
SELECT MIN(ImageId) as LowestImageId
FROM Mytable 
WHERE Processing = 0 
  AND Finished = 0
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a71d9/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(ImageId) FROM your_table WHERE Processing = 0 AND Finished = 0
```