# Why doesn't this query work? Combining Having and Where

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT fileUser FROM `images` 
HAVING min(imageid) AND 
WHERE (finished=0 and processing=0)
```

It seems a simple thing to get the `fileUser` index with the least `imageID` where finished and processing also = 0. But, I cannot seem to come up with a query that works? Any help would be great.

Comment: Please don't go away immediately after asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you question is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524784/finding-the-min-in-a-column-where-two-other-columns-are-zero), then you can try this one:

```
SELECT fileUser FROM `images`
WHERE imageid = (SELECT min(imageid) 
                 FROM `images` 
                WHERE finished=0 
                  AND processing=0)
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/188ec/1)

Comment: Thank you very much. That works perfectly. I had tried something similar to that, but wasn't using the second SELECT properly. this cleared it up.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be

```
SELECT fileUser 
FROM `images` 
WHERE finished=0 
AND processing=0
ORDER BY imageid
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he actually wants this

```
SELECT fileUser FROM `images`
WHERE imageid = (SELECT min(imageid) FROM `images` WHERE (finished=0 and processing=0))
```